# R: Sum each column, average cover value and relative average cover value

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe that contains percent cover data of many plant species in several plots:

Example

```
        sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
PlotA   1   12  0   0
PlotB   0   3   5   0
PlotC   3   0   0   1
PlotD   0   6   0   0
PlotE   1   1   0   0
```

I would like to calculate a few things for each individual species/column:

How many plots does each species occur? (ex. sp1 = 3, sp2 = 4, sp3 = 1)

What is the average pct. cover per species per plot? (total cover/total plots, ex. sp1 = 1.0, sp2 = 4.4)

What is the relative avg. pct. cover per species per plot? (avg. pct. cover/sum of all avg. pct cover)

Will this be more easily achieved by making the species the rows and the plots the columns?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean for the second and third questions. What do you mean by average and relative? You compute a mean?

Comment: can you computer by hand the result you want to obtain? question 2 and question 3 are not very clear to me

Comment: Q2: average percent cover of sp1 (1+0+3+0+1)/5 plots = cover of 1.0 per plot, sp2=4.4, sp3=1.0, sp4=0.2

Comment: Q3: relative avg. pct. cover of sp1: sp1 avg. pct. cover (1.0) / sum of all avg. pct. covers (1.0 + 4.4 + 1.0 + 0.2) * 100 = 1.0 / 6.6 * 100 = relative average cover of sp1 = 15.15

Comment: Q2 addresses what the average cover of a single species across all of the plots, Q3 standardizes the average cover of each species as a proportion of cover to all species present across all plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages to summarise and reshape the data. Look below;*

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # version 1.0.0

df1 %>% 
  summarise_all(list(count = ~sum(`>`(.,0)), 
                     avg.cover=~mean(.))) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  separate("key", into = c("SP", "var"), sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "var", values_from = "value") %>% 
  mutate(rel.avg.cover = avg.cover/sum(avg.cover))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   SP    count avg.cover rel.avg.cover
#>   <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 sp1       3       1          0.152 
#> 2 sp2       4       4.4        0.667 
#> 3 sp3       1       1          0.152 
#> 4 sp4       1       0.2        0.0303
```

***Data:***

```
read.table(text = "row  sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
PlotA   1   12  0   0
PlotB   0   3   5   0
PlotC   3   0   0   1
PlotD   0   6   0   0
PlotE   1   1   0   0", header=T, row.names=1) -> df1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution whithout packages, using colSums and colMeans

Data:

```
df = data.frame(sp1 = c(1,0,3,0,1),
                sp2 = c(12,3,0,6,1),
                sp3 = c(0,5,0,0,0),
                sp4 = c(0,0,1,0,0),
                row.names = paste("Plot",c("A","B","C","D","E"),sep=""))
```

Questions :

```
# question 1
pres = colSums(apply(df,2,function(x) x>0))
# question 2
pct = colMeans(df)
# question 3
rlt = pct/sum(pct)*100

df2 = data.frame(pres,pct,rlt)
df2
#     pres pct       rlt
# sp1    3 1.0 15.151515
# sp2    4 4.4 66.666667
# sp3    1 1.0 15.151515
# sp4    1 0.2  3.030303
```

Usually in Ecology, we put individual in row, but this transformation is easily achieveable by the `t()` function if you need it.